# Store ManagedObjectID in a NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmanagedobjectid

I am working on local notifications and in order to identify each notification it needs to get a `NSDictionary` with the `ManagedObjectID` from the Core Data model as key of that dictionary.

The problem is thatwhen I do this I get the following error:

```
Property list invalid for format: 200 (property list dictionaries may only have keys which are CFStrings, not 'CFType')
```

which has to do with the fact that dictionaries can only store certain data types and not NSManagedObjectID.

So my question is, is there a way to convert this `NSManagedObjectId` to a `NSString` or `NSNumber` for example. I really need that specific id in order to identify it later on to remove that specific notification.

Code thus far:

```
    -(void) scheduleNotificationAtDate:(NSDate*)date WithBody:(NSString*) body WithBillEventId:(NSManagedObjectID*) billEventId{

// Schedule the notification
UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.fireDate = date;
localNotification.alertBody = body;
localNotification.alertAction = @"Ga naar de Rekening Delen app";
localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1;

//set the dictionary here,
NSDictionary *billEventIdentifier = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"billevent_notification" forKey: billEventId];
localNotification.userInfo = billEventIdentifier;
NSLog(@"set local notification");
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having is that for objects to be properly stored in a dictionary and then serialized to disk they must be NSCoding compliant which NSManagedObjectID is not.

Fortunately there is another way.  There is a method on an NSManagedObjectID called `URIRepresentation` which will be you an identifier for a Core Data object and you can use that instead of storing the NSManagedObjectID.  You can then turn that NSURL URIRepresentation back into an NSManagedObjectID like this example:

```
NSManagedObjectID *objectID = [context.persistentStoreCoordinator managedObjectIDForURIRepresentation:myObjectURI];
```